# Is there possibility to synchronize data between two Azure blob storages

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a task to copy BLOB storage to the other location and make synchronization between them. Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution for it. Is there a possibility to make it more simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) utility to [synchronize files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#synchronize-files), or replicate a source location to a destination location.

The [azcopy sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync) command identifies all files at the destination, and then compares file names and last modified timestamps before the starting the sync operation. If you set the `--delete-destination` flag to `true` AzCopy deletes files without providing a prompt. If you want a prompt to appear before AzCopy deletes a file, set the `--delete-destination` flag to `prompt`.

Also check the [az storage blob sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_sync) from Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the newer: [Object Replication for Block Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/object-replication-overview).

> Object replication asynchronously copies block blobs between a source
> storage account and a destination account.